# Imported CSV file returning no values

Tags: csv, file-upload

I'm creating a module that will allow me to upload some data from a csv file to our database.  However, this file doesn't seem to be returning anything, any idea why?

```
public function uploadData(Varien_Object $object)
{
    $csvFile = $_FILES['groups']['name']['store_information']['fields']['basename_modulename_import']['value'];

    $io = new Varien_Io_File();
    $info = pathinfo($csvFile);
    $io->open(array('path' => $info['dirname']));
    $io->streamOpen($info['basename']);

    $headers = $io->streamReadCsv();
    Mage::log('what is headers? THIS: ' . $headers); //headers isn't anything
    Mage::log(empty($headers)); //returns true

    //$adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    //$adapter->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $rowNumber = 1;
        $importData = array();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }


    $io->streamClose();

}
```

The CSV file in question looks like:

```
LSK1, ls,2, rsk1,2, lsubk1,1, lsb1p,1
w12sb65r, w12,4, b65r,4, tmb,4, vs,4
hw907, aa10181,5
xftk5, hw438,1, xft2,1, fph2,1, fsu28,1, f225,1, hw242,1
tlk1, bulb1157,1, tlb1,2, tlba,2, tlbp1,1, tllg1,1, tll13,2, hw227,1
```

$info is set to:

```
Array(
    [dirname] => .
    [basename] => kitInventory.csv
    [extension] => csv
    [filename] => kitInventory
)
```

Comment: What does ` $info = pathinfo($csvFile);` return? Can you var_dump the  $info` variable?

Comment: @Sander sure thing, it's in the Q.

Comment: oh pfff, sorry, I need more coffee -.-

Comment: @Sander I just added it :D chug away though.  It's a monday on Earth.

Comment: @Sander Ah, thanks to my old friend ol' Brutus Forcicus i've discovered that the issue was in my attempt to retrieve the file by it's 'name' instead of it's 'tmp_name'.  Rather silly tbh, I don't need to save this file or anything only access it and discard is enough.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve funcitonality by changing:

```
$csvFile = $_FILES['groups']['name']['store_information']['fields']['basename_modulename_import']['value'];
```

to:

```
$csvFile = $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name']['store_information']['fields']['basename_modulename_import']['value'];
```

This allowed me to bypass the need to save the file and simply access it in magentos temporary file directory and process it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the path you're giving. Any uploaded file should (as far as I know) first be moved to a readable location.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338659/387136) should give you some details, below a snippet from the post

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {
    try {
        $fileName       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1));
        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
        $fileName       = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNamewoe) . '.' . $fileExt;

        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('file');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'jpg')); //allowed extensions
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'yourModuleFolder';
        if(!is_dir($path)){
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }
        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

When you've moved the file, I would suggest the the `import` folder under `var` you can pass that path to the `Varien_Io_File` class

Comment: Now it's throwing the following exception... DEBUG (7): Exception message: File was not uploaded.
Trace: #0 ...Csv.php(10): Varien_File_Uploader->__construct('file')